# How to check null condition in mysql before execute particular set of queries?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements, ifnull

I am trying to execute below script in different 5 databases.

```
SET @CONSTRAINT_NAME = (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'StudentMaster'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'StudentSubjectMa'
AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE());
```

Now, I want to check here that if `@CONSTRAINT_NAME` is `NOT NULL` then only below statements should be execute. is it possible?

```
    SET @DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE StudentSubjectMarksMap 
    DROP FOREIGN KEY `", @CONSTRAINT_NAME , "`");

    PREPARE DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL_STMT FROM @DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL;
    EXECUTE DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL_STMT;
    DROP PREPARE DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL_STMT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with standard `IF` statement:

```
IF @CONSTRAINT_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN 
    SET @DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE StudentSubjectMarksMap 
    DROP FOREIGN KEY `", @CONSTRAINT_NAME , "`");

    PREPARE DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL_STMT FROM @DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL;
    EXECUTE DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL_STMT;
    DROP PREPARE DROP_CONSTRAINT_SQL_STMT;
END IF
```

See [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi @vhu, Thanks but it is only possible within function() or procedures(). I want it with simple syntax only. I don't want to call function externally.

Comment: @vishal: Are you only running the SQL script or do you control it from PHP or Bash?

Comment: I want to run only SQL script.